# The remote computer disconnected the session because of an error in the licensing protocol

Tags: licensing

I have a Terminal Services user who is getting the error below when they try to RDP from a new PC that I have moved them to. We have 4 other TS users, neither of whom are having any problem connecting.

"The remote computer disconnected the session because of an error in the licensing protocol

Please try connecting to the remote computer again or contact your server administrator."

I tried deleting the license keys from here on the client machine: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\MSLicensing. But this hasn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a licensing issue. TS was set up with a per device license instead of a per user licence. In the end I had to swap an another PC that we still had a license for.